# Server 2008 not showing all the available GPO Policies

Tags: windows-server-2008, group-policy

I am using server 2008 R2 and when i am trying to use GPO many policies templates are missing, I make sure filter is off.

Please assist thanks

Comment: *many policies templates are missing*... Can you clarify what you mean? Perhaps post a screen shot slowing what you're seeing.